# Unable to import PySpark in python shell

Tags: python, pyspark

I tried adding the follownig in $SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark file:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH' along with 'export SPARK_HOME' to .bashrc file. In the bashrc I have given the path like this

export SPARK_HOME='/usr/bin/spark'

export PYTHONPATH='/usr/bin/spark/python/:/usr/bin/python'
```

Is this the right way? Because I am unable to import it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Putting your whole Spark installation under `/usr/bin` is not the right thing to do in the first place. `/usr/bin` is for executables. However that is a question of good style and should not prevent things from working. Are you sure that the `PYTHONPATH` is properly picked up? What is the output of `python -c 'import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)'`?

Comment: export SPARK_HOME=~/spark-1.2.0
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
This is how i did it!! :)